# How can I get the Instance ID of the EMR master instance in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

The following code gives me a list of all EC2 instances that are part of my cluster:

```
data "aws_instances" "emrMaster" {
  instance_tags {
    Name = "emr-cluster-name"
  }
}
```

But when I try to narrow the list using the AWS generated tag for the master instance, I get the same list.

```
data "aws_instances" "emrMaster" {
  instance_tags {
    Name = "emr-cluster-name"
    "aws:elasticmapreduce:instance-group-role" = "MASTER"
  }
}
```

If I remove the quotes on the key name, I get a illegal character error due to the colons in the key name.

```
data "aws_instances" "emrMaster" {
  instance_tags {
    Name = "emr-cluster-name"
    aws:elasticmapreduce:instance-group-role = "MASTER"
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, am I doing something wrong, or have I uncovered a bug in Terraform?

I am using Terraform v0.11.7

I am looking to capture this value so I can build specific cloudwatch alerts for the master instance that are different from the Core instances.

Comment: If you used Terraform to build the instances, you could use outputs from that code to get the IDs.

Comment: I found a way to find the Instance ID of the Master node in EMR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256438/aws-cli-emr-get-master-node-instance-id-and-tag-it does that help?

Comment: As far as I am aware `resource "aws_emr_cluster"` does not expose the ec2 instances, so using `data "aws_instances"` is the only way I think you can get at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose better use *aws_instance*  (not *aws_instances*)

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr-cluster" {
....
}

data "aws_instance" "master" {

  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${aws_emr_cluster.emr-cluster.name}"]
  }

  filter {
    name = "tag:aws:elasticmapreduce:instance-group-role"
    values = ["MASTER"]
  }
}
```

And then just use output:

```
output "master_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_instance.master.id}"
}
```

Comment: Using `filter` instead of `instance_tags` did the trick.  There is a known bug in terraform 0.11 where instance_tag keys containing ':' are not used as part of the criteria.  The bug does not seem to be impacting filter.